# Ctypes pass float into function returns random numbers

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, typeerror, ctypes

To give some background, I am using linux and I have a C code as follows:

```
int c_func(const char* dir, float a, float b, float c, float d )
{
    printf("%s\n", dir);
    printf("%f\n",a);
    printf("%f\n",b);
    printf("%f\n",c);
    printf("%f\n",d);

    return 0;
}
```

This is a simple function that takes in a string and 4 floats as arguments and prints them out as I am trying to test my phython/C interface. My python code is as follows:

```
calling_function = ctypes.CDLL("/home/ruven/Documents/Sonar/C interface/Interface.so")
calling_function.c_func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_float]
calling_function.c_func.restype =  ctypes.c_float

for _fv in _testFV:
                _predOut = calling_function.c_func("hello",_fv[0], _fv[1], _fv[2], _fv[3])
                exit(1)
```

To clarify, `_fv[0], _fv[1], _fv[2], _fv[3]` are `[1.969591, 112.7779, 1.8701470000000002, 111.7575]` respectively. And _testFV is a list of 117 other lists. I am just looking to extract the first list from _testFV.

After running this code, I am able to correctly print the string but the floats seem to be large random numbers (1849375168, 3, 4805786, 9397952) instead of the actual values of `_fv[0], _fv[1], _fv[2], _fv[3]`. So to check if I am passing the right values into the `calling_function.c_func` function,I included a print statement to print the value of `_fv[0], _fv[1], _fv[2], _fv[3]` and their types. I checked and the values are floats and the correct numbers are being inputted into the function but random numbers are being printed out. I thought that I might have declared restype wrongly, but I thought that restype should be declared as int as the C code returns 0.

Question 1: Why does the function print out random numbers instead of the floats that I input into the function.

Question 2: The function is supposed to print out 1 string and 4 floats so am I supposed to declare restype as 1 string and 4 floats?

Things I have tried:

1. Changing all the float variables to doubles.
2. Changing restype to int and double.
3. Changing the arguments of `calling_function.c_func` in python to `("hello",1,2,3,4)` and the function in python is able to print out the correct values. When I change the arguments to ("hello",1.2,2.3,3.4,4.3), it gives me random numbers again. I believe that there is some type declaration that I have done wrongly but I am not sure what.
4. Changing restype line to `calling_function.c_func.restype = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_float]` but this gives the following error: TypeError: restype must be a type, a callable, or None.

I am not really sure what is going on. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `c_float` for `argtypes` and `c_int` for `restype` works for me:

**foo.c:**

```
int
foo(const char* dir, float a, float b, float c, float d )
{
    printf("%s\n", dir);
    printf("%f\n", a);
    printf("%f\n", b);
    printf("%f\n", c);
    printf("%f\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

With Python 2.7:

```
>>> f = ctypes.CDLL('./foo.so')
>>> f.foo.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_float, ctypes.c_float]
>>> f.foo.restype = ctypes.c_int
>>> f.foo('hello', 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3)
hello
1.000000
1.100000
1.200000
1.300000
0
>>>
```

Comment: I just realized that there is an issue with my computer and that it was not saving the C files. I have managed to solve that and I am now able to run the program. I cannot delete this question as stackoverflow has given me a warning about deleting answered questions. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.